# How to assertRaises in unittest an exception caught in try except block?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, python-unittest

In my production function:

```
def myfunction():
   try:
        do_stuff()
        (...)
        raise MyException("...")
    except MyException as exception:
         do_clean_up(exception)
```

My test fails, because the exception is caught in the try/except block

```
def test_raise(self):
   with self.assertRaises(MyException):
       myfunction()
```

self.assertRaises is never called.

How to guarantee that the exception is caught during testing?

The exception is never asserted
`AssertionError: MyException not raised`

Comment: Worrying about whether an exception is raised and handled puts too much emphasis on the implementation of `myfunction`. Instead, focus on the state of your environment *after* `myfunction` returns.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you caught the exception `MyException` direct in `myFunction()`.

Comment out out the `try-except` clause and try again, test should pass.

`assertRaises` is used for uncaught errors. You can also re-raise in except block.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is handled internally, so there is no *external* evidence that the exception is raised.

However, both `MyException` and `do_clean_up` are external names, which means you can patch them and make assertions about whether they do or do not get used. For example,

```
# Make sure the names you are patching are correct
with unittest.mock.patch('MyException', wraps=MyException) as mock_exc, \
     unittest.mock.patch('do_clean_up', wraps=do_clean_up) as mock_cleanup:
    myfunction()
    if mock_exc.called:
        mock_cleanup.assert_called()
```